# Windows Git Bash window position

Tags: windows, git

I've installed the Git for Windows (from *git-scm.com*). I'd like to set the initial position of the Git Bash so in the `minttyrc` file I've added a line `Position=100,50` but that seems not work. The Windows itself always position the window at the random coords. Is the a working way to make the Git Bash window be always placed at the position i choose?

Answer (score 4):

First, ensure that Git does read this `minttyrc` file.

Then, replace the line of `Position=100,50` with these two lines:

```
X=100
Y=50
```

If they do not help, use instead of `minttyrc` the
positional command-line parameters of `mintty` available for your software.